# Trouble with GitHub and Ubuntu file permissions

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I recently tried to push my new files to my repo and things went haywire.  I also think there's a problem with my SSH.  Not really sure how to fix either of them.

The files were moved out of my project folder while attempting to push them to GitHub, which I'm terrible at. They disappeared out of my local development project folder.  It's a `.Rproj` folder.  They should be in here:

[image]

But I did something with GitHub that made them go poof.

I ran a search for the files with the following, and it shows that the files exist on my machine (it is my machine, no one else uses it), but I don't have permission to access the files.  Does anyone know how to fix this `./.gnupg` permission issue?

```
find $directory -type f -name "Rpackages/saber"
# find: `./.gnupg': Permission denied
find $directory -type f -name "Rpackages"
# find: `./.gnupg': Permission denied
find $directory -type f -name "playerStats.R"
# find: `./.gnupg': Permission denied
find . -print0 | grep -FzZ 'Rpackages/saber'
# find: `./.gnupg': Permission denied
# ./Rpackages/saber./Rpackages/saber/.Rhistory./Rpackages/saber/man./Rpackages/
# saber/man/franchise.info.Rd./Rpackages/saber/man/load.event.Rd./Rpackages/saber  
# man/load.roster.Rd./Rpackages/s ....
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to fix, you simply cannot go into `.gnupg` (which could have been created by `root` or for a different account than yours)

Put `sudo` before your command, or add `2> /dev/null` to its end if you want to ignore them.
Or you can take ownership of the .gnupg folder (if it is in your `/homle/myaccount` folder)

```
sudo chown -R myaccount ~myaccount/.gnupg
```

As shown in "[gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183030/6309)", the permission for that folder should be 700.

Comment: Thanks,.. just to clarify. What is `myaccount`?  My username on my machine?

Comment: @RichardScriven yes, the one you are currently logged on, and under which you are executing those `find` commands.

Comment: @RichardScriven move them back? You mean change the location of the `.gnupg` folder?

Comment: I want to get them out of there. It is a project full of 40 code files that were moved, not copied, moved.  I need them in specific folder so the package will run (and because I don't want to lose them. Btw, I don't know what the `./.gnupg` folder is/does

Comment: @RichardScriven you could, but I am not sure where "there" is: if that `.gnupg` is in your `/home/youraccount` folder, then moving it would break the default location for gpg config files (https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration.html)

Comment: @RichardScriven but if you moved all those files (included the `.gnupg`), then yes, you can remove that `.gnupg` folder (or at least move it aside): it doesn't do anything in its new place.

Comment: @RichardScriven just to be sure, that `.gnupg` folder doesn't affect you finding your other files, and moving them back. It just means those other files are not in `.gnupg`, because you cannot explorer that folder. If you found them elsewhere, you can restore them in your project, while ignoring completely this `.gnupg` issue.