# curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rvm, ubuntu-14.04

While Trying to run the command on Ubuntu 14.4, get following error,

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=enabled

    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
    100   184  100   184    0     0    112      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   112
    100 22865  100 22865    0     0  10152      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  105k
    Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.26.11.tar.gz
    Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.26.11/1.26.11.tar.gz.asc
    gpg: Signature made Tuesday 31 March 2015 03:22:13 AM IST using RSA key ID BF04FF17
    gpg: can't open `/home/nethra/.gnupg/pubring.gpg'
    gpg: keydb_search failed: file open error
    gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
    Warning, RVM 1.26.0 introduces signed releases and automated check of signatures when GPG software found.
    Assuming you trust Michal Papis import the mpapis public key (downloading the signatures).

    GPG signature verification failed for '/home/nethra/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.26.11.tgz' - 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.26.11/1.26.11.tar.gz.asc'!
    try downloading the signatures:

        sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

    or if it fails:

        command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | sudo gpg --import -

    the key can be compared with:

        https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc
        https://keybase.io/mpapis
```

Tried Downloadin signature via,

```
$ sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file `/home/nethra/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: external program calls are disabled due to unsafe options file permissions
gpg: keyserver communications error: general error
gpg: keyserver receive failed: general error
```

Ran following command as per the command's suggestion:

```
$ curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | sudo gpg --import -

gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file `/home/nethra/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: key D39DC0E3: "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

What is the wrong that I am doing? or Is there any permission or configuration that I have missed to provide?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file, $gpg --fingerprint on Ubuntu9.10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182938/gpg-warning-unsafe-ownership-on-configuration-file-gpg-fingerprint-on-ubun)