# How do I fix "gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/jonny/.gnupg'" when using gpg?

Tags: ubuntu, gnupg

I'm trying to install chirpstack on my ubuntu machine. When trying to set up the key I get the following errors.

```
jonny@jonny-ubuntu:~$ sudo gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 1CE2AFD36DBCCA00
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/jonny/.gnupg'
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
```

Link to the tutorial I'm using: [chirpstack.io](https://www.chirpstack.io/guides/debian-ubuntu/).
Similar questions I have followed on StackOverflow/ Stackexchange (Didn't work for me) [gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/user/.gnupg'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452020/gpg-warning-unsafe-ownership-on-homedir-home-user-gnupg)
. [gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file, $gpg ....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182938/gpg-warning-unsafe-ownership-on-configuration-file-gpg-fingerprint-on-ubun)

```
jonny@jonny-ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Sorry if the question is too vague or does not make sense, feel free to ask me any additional questions. Thanks In advance.

Comment: Did the solution given on those questions not work for you? Like this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452025

Comment: No it doesn't. Sorry I should have clarified in the post

Comment: What is the USER: GROUP on ~/.gnupg set to?

Comment: `jonny@jonny-ubuntu:~$ sudo ls -la ~/.gnupg
[sudo] password for jonny: 
total 24
drw-------  4 jonny jonny 4096 Mar 16 11:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 37 jonny jonny 4096 Mar 16 08:28 ..
drwx------  2 jonny jonny 4096 Mar 16 10:52 crls.d
drwx------  2 jonny jonny 4096 Nov 29 11:35 private-keys-v1.d
-rw-------  1 jonny jonny   32 Nov 29 14:13 pubring.kbx
srwx------  1 jonny jonny    0 Mar 16 11:32 S.dirmngr
-rw-------  1 jonny jonny 1200 Nov 29 14:13 trustdb.gpg`

I had to use sudo or else I was getting permission denied

Comment: You shouldn't be getting permission denied when just trying to run ls -la. Check if your user is in the sudo group: groups jonny

Comment: This is the first line of output:
`drwxr-xr-x 37 jonny jonny  4096 Mar 16 08:28  .`
Heres the line with the .gnupg:
`drw-------  4 jonny jonny  4096 Mar 16 11:32  .gnupg`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209705/discussion-between-captivecorsair-and-jonny).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are consistently getting errors when trying to retrieve the key from the server, then you will need to retrieve the key and add it to apt trusted keys manually using:

```
wget -q "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x1CE2AFD36DBCCA00" -O- | gpg --dearmor > 1CE2AFD36DBCCA00.gpg
sudo mv 1CE2AFD36DBCCA00.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
```

After that, you should be able to install the software